# Binary Search Tree (BST) successor for nonexistent node

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I want to get the successor of a node even though it's not in the binary search tree.
For example, if BST has nodes {1,4,15,68,90} and I call successor method:
successor(20) the method should return 68, rather than null.

Comment: And...? What have you tried?

Comment: If you've written your own implementation, finding the successor of a nonexistent node is almost exactly the same as finding the successor of an existing node. If you're using a BST of some library, you'd need to specify which one.